# How I can generate my own sparkle link in the appcast config xml file and how can I add my own enclosure URL in the upgarder package flutter

Tags: flutter

How I can generate my own sparkle link in the appcast config xml file and how can I add  my own enclosure URL in the upgarder package flutter

Added upgarder widget after that How I can generate my own sparkle link in the appcast config xml file and how can I add  my own enclosure URL in the upgarder package flutter